# Displaying edittext input on another activity

Tags: android

I am having quite a simple problem.
I want to take an numerical input in an activity then display that on another activity.

**input.java**

```
Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inputok);
ok.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener ()
{

    public void onClick(View vie)
    {EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ei);
    a = Integer.valueOf(et.getText().toString());


        Intent intent= new Intent (input.this, answer.class);
     intent.putExtra("i", a );
    startActivity(intent);
    }
} );
```

Now before displaying it on another i want to perform some action on the integer, say +1 to it.

**answer.java**

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
int a = extras.getInt("i");
++a;
TextView TV= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
TV.setText(a);
```

When i try to run this, the app closes, is there something wrong with the code??

Comment: post the logcat error msg here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i hope the problem is to set the integer value in an `setText();`

Try this,

```
   int intent_data = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("i"); // to Get the data

     // Now increment the value.
     int newVal= intent_data+1; // or intent_data++;
     TextView TV= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
      TV.setText(""+newVal);
```

or you can use,

```
 int intent_data = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("i"); // to Get the data

         // Now increment the value.
         int newVal= intent_data+1;
         TextView TV= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);

      String s = String.valueOf(newVal);
    TV.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert the integer to string before setting it to the textview, like this,

```
Integer.toString(a);
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

The problem is **TV.setText(a);**

we can only set CharSequence in setText method you are try to set integer value its wrong

please try it **TV.setText(""+a);**

I hope your code working fine after getting it.